# Open 2 separate MS Outlook email

Tags: microsoft-outlook

What are the command keys to open a 2nd MS Outlook email? I will have one open with emails and the other open with calendars so I can more quickly work tasks.

Comment: Double-clicking your Outlook icon again doesn't work? What version of Outlook are you using? What operating system; Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7 (at least), if the Outlook icon is pinned to the taskbar, you can right-click it and select "Outlook 2013" (or whatever your version is), and a new instance of the application should open. Left-clicking the icon normally only restores/minimizes the already open instance.

Comment: Shift+left click = Start another instance, as mentioned by Techie007.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows 7 or later, and Office 2010 or later:

If you have Outlook open already you can get another instance open multiple ways:

1. Just (double) click the Outlook icon again from your Start Menu or wherever you started the first instance from.
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking the Outlook icon on the taskbar.
3. Click the Outlook taskbar icon with your middle mouse button.
4. Left-click the Outlook icon on your taskbar, and select "Microsoft Outlook" from the menu that appears.